# Helm super chart

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm, helm3

We have 2 helm-charts:

1. helm-chart-A which deploys:

   - A-config-map
   - A-deployment
   - A-secret
2. helm-chart-B which deploys:

   - B-config-map
   - B-statefulset
   - B-secret

Is it possible to create an empty super hart which include the above as dependencies and deploy them?

e.g

helm-chart-C:

- Chart.yaml:

  - dependencies:

    - helm-chart-A
    - helm-chart-B

--> Output:

- Deploy helm-chart-A and helm-chart-B

In case yes, is it possible to specify as well the "helm.sh/hook-weight"? e.g. helm-chart-B has to be deployed before A

I use an example 2 charts but we have 7/8 charts that we want to deploy with an "helm super chart"

Comment: What happens if you try to deploy this `helm-chart-C`; are there any specific problems you run into?  In practice this could encounter trouble if the charts A and B have similar dependencies, in that Helm will only install the dependency once and the two charts must have compatible version constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new chart C with two [subcharts](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/) A and B, or just add them as [dependencies](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/), but you cannot easly control the execution order between the two charts (deploying all resources from A before B), you will have something like:

- A-Namespace
- B-Namespace
- A-StatefulSet
- B-ReplicaSet
- A-Service
- B-Service

To force helm to deploy the resources (not the charts) in some order, you can use [helm hooks weights](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/).

Answer (score 2):

yes. Exactly the way you said:

```
helm-chart-C:
    Chart.yaml:
        dependencies:
            helm-chart-A
            helm-chart-B
```

as for ordering. Other than the hack of using helm hook's. There is none. Your charts shouldn't need to care about each other. Else they should be the same chart